# SQL Server : query distinct one column only and doesn't included the succeeding column

Tags: sql-server

I've tried using `Distinct`, `Group By` and `Having`; none of them are able to produce my desired result.

I tried a query like this:

```
Select Distinct 
    EventID,
    EventName
from 
    [dbo].[Event]
group by 
    EventID, EventName
having 
    count(EventName) > 0
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Data is text, and should be supplied an `text`. If you have a `GROUP BY` why do you have a `DISTINCT` as well? A query with a `GROUP BY` will only return 1 row per distinct set; so there's no need for a `DISTINCT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following, using `GROUP BY` and `MIN`. You don't need `DISTINCT` or a mixture of `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`. It looks like you want to get also the count of events per artist / event:

```
SELECT MIN(EventID) AS ID, EventName, COUNT(EventID)
FROM [Event]
GROUP BY EventName
ORDER BY MIN(EventID) ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=417915eae0c3bb2274df2afeaa3fa1cc)

Answer (score 1):

An `ORDER BY` the window function `ROW_NUMBER` in combination with a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` can be used for this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
 EventID, 
 EventName
FROM [dbo].[Event] 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventName ORDER BY EventID ASC);
```

And if the result needs to be sorted by something, then use a sub-query.

```
SELECT EventID, EventName
FROM
(
    SELECT
     EventID, 
     EventName,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventName ORDER BY EventID ASC) as rn
    FROM [dbo].[Event] 
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY EventName;
```